# Why select what option was added dynamic shows all option in title?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I've added `option` in `select` through `jQuery`

```
$('.select_month').append('<option value=month_'+i+'>'+i+</option>');
```

And this is my `HTML`.

```
<select class="select_month" name="month"> </select>
```

But it's not working correctly when executed. 
It shows like this:

[image]

When click this..

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: We need a bit more code, or a jsFiddle, please.

Comment: `('<option value=month_'+i+'>'+i+</option>');` just typo or not? It should be `('<option value="month_'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Thanks but same work T_T

Comment: can you provide full jquery code together with HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like this?

HTML:

```
<select class="select_month" name="month"> </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    for (i=1; i<13; i++)
    {
        $('.select_month').append('<option value=month_'+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
    }
});
```